# Satellizer with Sails

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, sails.js, satellizer

I would like to implement local authentication and authentication via social networks in a [Sails](http://sailsjs.org) app which is developed as an API server.

I tried passportjs and sails-auth-generator but I think they are more meant towards sails apps which render server side views and requires extra logic if implemented in a restful app.

With that I found the [Satellizer auth module](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) and would really like to use it over the passportjs mess.

It also has very clean examples for authentication with different networks:
[Auth Examples for Expressjs](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js).

Also, It has client side angularjs directives for plug-n-play use.

But, I am unable to figure out how should I port the whole ExpressJs example to sailsjs terminology of services, policies etc since this is new for me.
Please assist with the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Try asking around in here. They should have some good answers as well. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails